# XmlHttpRequest overrideMimeType for outgoing data

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I want `XmlHttpRequest` to not touch (i.e. convert to `UTF-8` or any other encoding) any of the characters it is sending and receiving to/from server.

For the characters received from the server, I know I can do `XmlHttpRequest#overrideMimeType('text/plain; charset=x-user-defined')` and the characters are left alone.

However, for the characters sent to the server via `XmlHttpRequest#send` call, I couldn't find a way to tell `XmlHttpRequest` to not touch those characters. I see that `XmlHttpRequest` encodes them into `UTF-8` no matter what I tried. Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: did you ever figure this out? I'm stumped on it.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar problem to upload audio grabbed from a microphone (via flash).
Here is how I solved it (tested in FF 9 and chromium 15). The following js code takes a binary input as a string, and uploads it to the server without any alterations/encoding.
Hopefully this can be of use to someone.

```
    var audioBytes = <the data you want sent untouched>
    var crlf = '\r\n';
    var body = '';
    var doubleDash = '--';
    var boundary = '12345678901234567890';

    var file = {
            name: "online-recording.wav",
            type: "audio/x-wav",
            size: audioBytes.length,
            recordedContent: audioBytes
    };

    var body = doubleDash + boundary + crlf +
            'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; ' +
            'filename="' + unescape(encodeURIComponent(file.name)) + '"' + crlf +
            'Content-Type: ' + file.type + crlf + crlf +
            file.recordedContent + crlf +
            doubleDash + boundary + doubleDash + crlf;

    // copy binary content into a ByteArray structure, so that the browser doesn't mess up encoding
    var audioByteArray = new Uint8Array(body.length);

    for (var i=0; i< audioByteArray.length; i++) {
            audioByteArray[i] = body.charCodeAt(i);
    }

    // use an XMLHttpRequest to upload the file
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    console.log(xhr.readyState);
    };
    xhr.open('post', url, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');

    // setup AJAX event handlers here

    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data; boundary=' + boundary);
    xhr.send(audioByteArray.buffer);
```

The trick is to build the request from an ArrayBuffer, which is seen as binary data, so the browser doesn't mess with it. Alternatively, if you only target firefox, you could use xhr.sendAsBinary() (from what I've read, it's not ported to any other browser, whereas the above code seems W3C compliant)

Comment: +1, this is described in https://developer.mozilla.org/En/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Sending_binary_data , and was apparently new in FF9.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to encode the data you send in base64. As far as I know, that'll always be valid, whatever encoding that is in (UTF-8/Latin-1/whatever).

Comment: Yes, but then I'd need to decode base64 on the server, so that would defeat the purpose. I want the chars to be send as they are to the server.

Comment: Yeah, but as far as I know it's the best method to make sure that everything the server receives is actually what the client sent. Also it's possible to just UTF-8 decode your string :) You should have the original back, I think.